# Why are trailing line breaks stripped when used as an argument (for echo)?

Tags: shell, text-processing, echo, text-formatting, text

When I run this…

```
echo "          



fdsfsd
dsfsdf



"
```

I really get the output of all these lines.

However, if I use this output as an argument for echo again…:

```
echo "$(echo "



fdsfsd
dsfsdf



")"
```

…I do only get the leading new lines, not the trailing ones:

```
(4 empty lines)  




fdsfsd
dsfsdf
```

So: **Why does this happen?** (Note I explicitly quoted the output of the `$()`, so I thought that would prevent such things.)
And **how can I prevent this?**

(tested with zsh)

BTW, same result if I use `printf` instead of `echo` – although the former obviously always misses the last line break `echo` would usually add.